# (FS0193, FS1113) F# Vector class with Statically Resolved Type Parameters

Tags: generics, types, f#

I am trying to implement a generic `Vector< ^F>` class in F#, where `^F` is the underlying field type of the vector's elements.
That means, `^F` can be anything that satisfies adding, subtracting, multiplying, and negating.

Some example user code could look like that:

```ml
    let v = Vector<int>([| 1; 2; 3 |])
    let w = Vector<int>([| 4; 5; 6 |])
    let sum = v + w
```

So here I use type `int`, and it could be **anything** that satisfies the underlying basic operations noted above. I seem to get *some* version working when using .NET style generics, but there I'm having issues too. Since I want to use SRTP anyways, I went this route again:

```ml
    type Vector< ^F when ^F : (static member (~-): ^F -> ^F)
                     and ^F : (static member (+): ^F * ^F -> ^F)
                     and ^F : (static member (*): ^F * ^F -> ^F)
               >(_values: ^F[]) =
        let values: ^F [] = _values
        member inline this.Values = values

        member inline this.Dimension = Array.length values

        // Constructs a Vector using given initializer
        static member inline Init (n: int) (initializer: (int -> ^F)) =
            Vector< ^F>(Array.init n (fun i -> initializer (i + 1)))

        member inline this.Item with get (i: int) = values.[i - 1]

        // negate a vector
        static member inline ( ~- ) (a: Vector< ^F>) =
            Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length a.Values) (fun i -> -a.[i])

        // sum of two vectors
        static member inline ( + ) (a: Vector< ^F>, b: Vector< ^F>): Vector< ^F> =
            Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length a.Values) (fun i -> a.[i] + b.[i])

        // difference of two vectors
        static member inline ( - ) (a: Vector< ^F>, b: Vector< ^F>): Vector< ^F> =
            Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length a.Values) (fun i -> a.[i] + (-b.[i]))

        // scale vector by scalar
        static member inline ( * ) (a: ^F, b: Vector< ^F>): Vector< ^F> =
            Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length b.Values) (fun i -> a * b.[i])
```

But the errors I am getting are motivation-exhausting, such as:

- **FS0193** (warning): `A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when ( ^F or  ^?12844) : (static member ( + ) :  ^F *  ^?12844 ->  ^F)'` (but also on operator `-` and `*`)
- **FS1113** (error): `The value 'Values' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not` - this is basically all over the place, and is being reported for every member property, member function and static member function.

(The code snipped above is copy'n'paste-compatible for easy reproduction)

How do I solve the problem of constructing a type, such as Vector, whos elements and operations all have a statically resolved type parameter (or generic) with no errors.

Answer (score 8):

SRTP errors are horrible to diagnose, and it's considered a bug that the internally generated type ID leaks into user space. It's arguably not clear with the error message, but the static members don't satisfy all constraints. If you factor out the operators into a separate module, then type inference is able to take care of applying all constraints (as of F# 4.6):

```
type Vector< ^F when ^F : (static member (~-): ^F -> ^F)
                and ^F : (static member (+): ^F * ^F -> ^F)
                and ^F : (static member (*): ^F * ^F -> ^F)
           >(_values: ^F[]) =
    let values: ^F [] = _values

    member inline __.Values = values
    member inline __.Dimension = Array.length values

    // Constructs a Vector using given initializer
    static member inline Init (n: int) (initializer: (int -> ^F)) =
        Vector< ^F>(Array.init n (fun i -> initializer (i + 1)))

    member inline __.Item with get (i: int) = values.[i - 1]

[<AutoOpen>]
module VectorOps =
    let inline ( ~- ) (v: Vector< ^F>) =
        Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length v.Values) (fun i -> -v.[i])

    let inline ( + ) (a: Vector< ^F>)  (b: Vector< ^F>) =
        Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length a.Values) (fun i -> a.[i] + b.[i])

    let inline ( - ) (a: Vector< ^F>)  (b: Vector< ^F>) =
        Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length a.Values) (fun i -> a.[i] - b.[i])

    let inline ( * ) (k: ^F)  (v: Vector< ^F>) =
        Vector< ^F>.Init (Array.length v.Values) (fun i -> k * v.[i])
```

You can then use this as expected:

```
let v1 = Vector<int>([|1;2;3;4;5|])
let v2 = Vector<int>([|1;2;3;4;5|])

let negv1 = -v1
negv1.Values |> Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%d " x)

let sum  = v1 + v2
sum.Values |> Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%d " x)

let diff = sum - v2
diff.Values |> Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%d " x)

let scaled = 3 * diff
scaled.Values |> Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%d " x)
```

Unfortunately, this is wading into the kind of territory where you run into nasty ends of the F# compiler. SRTP wasn't really designed for this style of programming, and though it certainly works, that lack of intention for this scenario really does leak out in the quirks and error messages.

Comment: Oh my God, @phillip, I have to thank you sooo much. But pl are tell me, if that wasn't meant to be used like thisz how can one implement vector/matrix/algebraic mathematical operations and types with a placeholder as the underlying field type in F#? My end goal here is to not repeat myself when `^F` can be not just ijt, float, BigRational but also symbolic expressions. I had a version working but never understood WTH I had such errors as above when trying to do it the way I wanted. So really, many thanks, man!

Comment: Also, I am coming from a strong C++ background and SRTP to me looked very much like C++ templates. And it surely looj d just like that when reading documentation.

Comment: Hey Phillip, I tried your code above, even with copy'n'pasting. and it is [unfortunately] still generating the error FS1113 on all `Vector< ^F>` members, such as Values, Dimension, Item. I am using VS2019 with F# 4.6 (and dotnet core 3 preview) however. I do not see a reason in why I am getting this error message, because I don't know what the compiler meant with "internal or private" functions that it says I am using here. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

I want to suggest you an existing solution for what you want to do.

The library [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) provides many solutions to deal with this in a consistent way.

I think a nice feature for this type of vectors is [Applicative Math Operators](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-applicative.html#Examples) (see the code section titled "Using applicative math operators").

Here's an example with your code:

```
#r @"FSharpPlus.dll"
open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data
open FSharpPlus.Math.Applicative

let v = ZipList [| 1; 2; 3 |]
let w = ZipList [| 4; 5; 6 |]
let sum = v .+. w

// val it : ZipList<int> = ZipList (seq [5; 7; 9])

let mul = v .*. w

// val it : ZipList<int> = ZipList (seq [4; 10; 18])
```

You can also do operations against scalars:

```
v .* 6 ;;
// val it : ZipList<int> = ZipList (seq [6; 12; 18])

7 +. w ;;
val it : ZipList<int> = ZipList (seq [11; 12; 13])
```

The underlying abstraction used here are [Applicative Functors](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-applicative.html), since a vector (think of a ZipList as a Vector) is an Applicative Functor it simply works.

ZipList, are a bit standard in the FP world, but alternatively you can also have a look at the [ParallelArray](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/master/src/FSharpPlus/ParallelArray.fs) applicative. If you don't like the names you can copy-paste the code and change the definition to:

```
type TVector<'t> =
| Scalar of 't
| Vector of 't array
...
let v = Vector [| 1; 2; 3 |]
v .* 6 ;;
// or
v .*. Scalar 6
```

And finally, if you don't want to use the library, you can use it as inspiration and copy the code you need. It's just there, and it works.

**NOTE**

Regarding your original code, if you have a look at the sources I pointed you, you'll see that it uses a more functional approach and for instance it doesn't restrict the type parameter at the type level, instead it restrict the functions.

```
type Vector< ^F>(_values: ^F[]) =
     let values: ^F [] = _values
     member inline this.Values = values

     member inline this.Dimension = Array.length values

     // Constructs a Vector using given initializer
     static member inline Init (n: int) (initializer: (int -> 'f)) =
         Vector<'f>(Array.init n (fun i -> initializer (i + 1)))

     member inline this.Item with get (i: int) = values.[i - 1]


     // negate a vector
     static member inline ( ~- ) (a: Vector<'f>) =
         Vector<'f>.Init (Array.length a.Values) (fun i -> -a.[i])
```

Note how capital `ˆF` is only used at the type level, whereas in the functions (or static members) a different type parameter is used, lowercase `'f`.

Comment: my problem I am trying to fix and understand isn't going away nor solved with FSharpPlus; I will however have a look at it, so thanks.

Comment: Well, you can also see how this problem is fixed in F#+. I added a note explaining it.